# Is there any way to cancel the popup navigation in Xamarin Prism?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

In Xamarin.Forms Prism, is there any way to cancel the popup navigation?

For example, I called navigation method to navigate to one popup page. But I for some reasons, I want to cancel that navigation before that navigation completed.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `IConfirmNavigation` to prevent the Navigation if the result is false. It will not cancel the navigation, but instead make sure if navigation is possible before it even happens (which makes more sense anyway)

You need to implement `IConfirmNavigation` to your ViewModel:

```
public class ContactPageViewModel : IConfirmNavigation 
{
  public bool CanNavigate(NavigationParameters parameters)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now whenever you're trying to navigate, it will check this method to see if `CanNavigate` is true.

Source: https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/confirming-navigation.html